# Dynamic fields in xml response in Gin Golang

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm sending XML response in an API that has some dynamic fields. The fields names are unknown and are dynamically created -

```
xmlMap := map[string] string {
    "Field1": "Value1",
    "Field2": "Value2",
}
c.Header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
c.XML(res.Code, xmlMap)
```

I want the response to be an XML starting with `Response` element like this -

```
<Response>
    <Field1>Value1</Field1>
    <Field2>Value2</Field2>
    <Field3>Value3</Field3>
</Response>
```

With above coding I'm not getting the xml response but the parent element is `map` and not `Response`.

I tried doing this as well but no help -

```
xmlMap := map[string]map[string] string{
    "Response": {
        "Field1": "Value1",
        "Field2": "Value2",
    },
}
c.Header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
c.XML(res.Code, xmlMap)
```